# How do I prove that $S_A\cong S_B\implies |A|=|B|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, axiom-of-choice

Let $A,B$ be infinite sets such that $S_A\cong S_B$. (Symmetric groups are group isomorphic)

How do I prove that $|A|=|B|$?

The only proof I know uses Axiom of choice. (That is, using AC to give orders to infinite family of finite sets)

Is there a way to prove this not invoking AC?

Comment: How do you prove it with choice?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The proof is illustrated in series of exercises in Dummit&Foote-Abstract. Let $D$ be the subgroup of permutations which move only finite elements then "view each permutation" as an element of $S_n$ some for $n$. Let $A$ be a subgroup of $D$ of which permutations are even in $S_n$, then show that $A$ is an infinite simple group.

Comment: I don't quite see the axiom of choice being used yet.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Right. I just realized that. It's because for "any" ordering of those finite sets would lead the unique signature, right?

Comment: However, the next step follwed by above argument definitely requires choice, but I see the use of choice in this step is reasonable.

Comment: I think that being an even permutation is independent of choice of enumerating the finite sets. In which case we didn't use the axiom of choice quite yet.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, that's what I exactly said. Thank you.

Comment: So what use of choice is in the next step?

Comment: In exercises Exercises 4.6.8 in Dummit and Foote gives the fact that the countable union and finite products of sets of cardinality $|\Omega|$ also have the cardinality $|\Omega|$ if $\Omega$ is infinite. I think the axiom of choice is used in there.

Comment: @tetori: Yes, the axiom of choice is necessary for that. Where is this fact used in the process?

Comment: Dummit and Foote gives two steps to prove it: First, subgroup $A$ mentioned above is the unique minimal normal subgroup of the permutation group. Second, (maybe) from the axiom of choice to prove that $|A|=|D|=|\Omega|$, where $S_\Omega$ is the permutation group we treated.

Comment: The discussion there http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12943/can-the-symmetric-groups-on-sets-of-different-cardinalities-be-isomorphic is perhaps interesting.